# When will a blocking socket timeout?

Tags: python, sockets, connection-timeout

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket-objects) of the `socket` module it is written that:

> Sockets are always created in blocking mode. In blocking mode,
>   operations block until complete or the system returns an error (such
>   as connection timed out).

Also, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25448603/501663) says:

> By default, if no explicit timeout is set for the socket, it will
>   block while doing so and eventually timeout, raising exception
>   `socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`

My question is, in what situation a blocking socket (or is it the OS?) will raise a timeout? Can I have some control over this timeout, or is the only thing I can do is to catch the exception?

**EDIT** Am I mixing the socket timeout with connection timeout? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set them, your Operating System will control the connect timeout. TCP/IP in blocking mode has three different timeouts:

- Connect.
- Read.
- Write.

To access connect timeouts and to understand how TCP/IP connect work, you should check out the **tcp_syn_retries** system configuration value on Linux.

**EDIT**: connect phrase contains some SYNC "handshake" packets while read/write phrase is a "normal" packet. That is the difference.