# How do I loop ports to scan?

Tags: python-2.7, loops, networking, port-scanning

I have this problem with a portscanner which keeps hanging at scanning port 1. How can I solve this problem?

```py
    #! /usr/bin/env python

    import socket 
    import subprocess
    from datetime import datetime

    #Clear the screen
    subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

    def portscan():
        server = raw_input("Enter the server to scan: ")
        serverIP = socket.gethostbyname(server)

        # Printing banner with information about host
        print "[+] Host: {} [+]\nIP Address: {}\n".format(server, serverIP)
        print "[!] Please wait, scanning for open services...\n"

        #Time when scan started.
        t1 = datetime.now()

        try:
            for port in range(1, 1024):
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                result = sock.connect_ex((serverIP, port))
                if result == 0:
                    print "[+] Port {}: Status:OPEN\n".format(result)
                    sock.close()

        except socket.gaierror:
            print "Hostname could not be resolved, Exiting...\n"
            sys.exit()

        except socket.error:
           print "Couldn\'t connect to server, Exiting\n"
           sys.exit()

        #Checking time again
        t2 = datetime.now()
        #Calculate duration of scan
        totaltime = t2 - t1

        print "Scan completed, duration: {}\n".format(totaltime)
```

> What happens when i run it i give it a hostname and resolve it to a IP
>   Address but whenever the scan starts it keeps scanning port 1 as i saw
>   in Wireshark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you maybe need a `timeout`.

Eventually, your `sock.connect_ex( )`, will to raise an exception `socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`, as you can read more about it, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25448603/3290239).

But the default timeout could be 120 seconds, and maybe you don't want to wait so much. So, you can set your own timeout, like that:

```py
try:
    for port in range(1, 1024):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(10) #timeout set for wait up 10 seconds.
        result = sock.connect_ex((serverIP, port))
        sock.settimeout(None)
```

To know why to use `sock.settimeout(None)`, and see another ways of setting `timeout`, you can read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432102/python-socket-connection-timeout).

I'm not sure if it was what you're looking for, but I hope it may help.